How to implement Service Provider Update In Laravel 11 Upgrade Guide
I'm upgrading our current system from Laravel 10 to 11 and I am not updating our application structure to the new structure. I already done all the upgrade things except for 1 item.
I have providers array here under config/app.php. In the upgrade guide (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/upgrade#publishing-service-providers), there's an item here about "Publishing Service Providers to the Application". it says here that I have to utilize the addProviderToBootstrapFile function. The instruction is unclear to where should I put this code? Also I don't have the bootstrap/providers.php file. Can someone tell me how do I go about this?

The addProviderToBootstrapFile method is primarily intended for package developers who are publishing service providers to applications. If you're working on an application (not a package) and your providers are already registered in config/app.php, you don't need to use this method.
